# JavaScript If statement ERROR - null is not an object (evaluating

Tags: javascript

I am using TagUI(js based automation tool) and javascript, and while writing code to extract information from the a string I receive a  "null is not an object (evaluating 'd1.match(/(Internet provider)(.*)(<br/>)/ig)[0];'

Where d1 can contain a couple of fields that I want to extract as parameters if a certain field is not available I would like to replace it with "not applicable"

examples:

```
d1 = "<p>please create a new entry.</p> <p>Person's name: Tom Jones<br/> Company: some company <br/> address: street one <br/> Employee ID: 07092120 <br/></p> "
OR
d1 = "<p>please create a new entry.</p> <p>Person's name: Jon Tomes<br/> Company: some company2 <br/> address: street two <br/><br/> Internet provider: O2 <br/> Employee ID: 07092121 <br/></p>"
```

I have tried the following expressions with no luck

```
provider = d1.match(/(Internet provider)(.*)(<br\/>)/ig)[0];
```

```
if (typeof ((d1.match(/(Internet provider)(.*)(<br\/>)/ig)[0]) === 'object' && (d1.match(/(Internet provider)(.*)(<br\/>)/ig)[0]) !== null)){provider=(d1.match(/(Internet provider)(.*)(<br\/>)/ig)[0]);}else{provider="not applicable"; }
```

```
if (d1.match(/(Internet provider)(.*)(<br\/>)/ig)[0] !== null){provider="not applicable";}else{provider = d1.match(/(Internet provider)(.*)(<br\/>)/ig)[0];}
```

```
if (typeof (provider = d1.match(/(Internet provider)(.*)(<br\/>)/ig)[0]) !== 'string'){provider="not applicable";}else{provider=d1.match(/(Internet provider)(.*)(<br\/>)/ig)[0]; }
```

Comment: If `.match()` doesn't match anything, the result is null. `.match()[0]` would throw an error in that case.

Comment: You need to do it in 2 steps. First call `match()` and assign this result to a variable. Then test if `match` is not null and if it is you can assign `variable[0]` to `provider`.

Comment: You could also use the conditional chaining operator `.?[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

[@VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71069130/javascript-if-statement-error-null-is-not-an-object-evaluating/71069488#comment125632237_71069130) did the trick:

> If `.match()` doesn't match anything, the result is null. `.match()[0]` would throw an error in that case.